# Return part of object props

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Is there more elegant way to return a part of object props? It's a bit awkward to type props twice.

```js
(async() => {

    let { id, status, type, name, format } = await Gimme();
    // Promise returns { id, status, type, name, format, width, height, size, ratio, ext }

    return { id, status, type, name, format };

})()
```

Comment: Try this: `return { id, status, type, name, format } = await Gimme();`

Comment: nevermind, that doesn't work

Comment: Create a helper function to pick object fields, as explained in the duplicate.